# Issue with a Form Submission on Return Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, zip, submit

I am fumbling for reasons for why I can't get this script to work when a "return" key is pressed. The form works when I try to submit via clicking the "GO" button yet not when the "Return" key is pressed via keyboard. I'm a bit outside my comfort zone on this project but about have it working.

https://jsfiddle.net/jbrewlet/9rjhzox5/

```
<h1 id="header">Are you in our delivery area?</h1>

<form action="action_page.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="zipCode">
   <input type="button" onClick="checkZipcode()" value="GO"></input>
</form>

<p1 id="resultText"></p1>

<script>
function checkZipcode(){
  var zipcodes = [12345,12344,12343];
  var validCode = false;
  for(i=0;i<zipcodes.length;i++){
    if (zipcodes[i] == document.getElementById('zipCode').value)
    {
        document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "YES, we deliver to your area!";
        return true;
    }
  }
    document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "<div id='fail'><em>Not yet, maybe next year!</em><br>We can <a href='http://google.com' target='blank';>notify you</a> when we deliver to your area.<br></div>";
    return false;

}
    </script>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign an onsubmit event on the form which will run when the form attempts to submit which will include hitting enter when inside the form.  Here is the altered code with changes in comments:

```
<h1 id="header">Are you in our delivery area?</h1>
<!-- Added id field to form so I could select it below -->
<form action="action_page.php" method="GET" id="zipCodeForm">
    <input type="text" id="zipCode">
   <input type="button" onClick="checkZipcode()" value="GO"></input>
</form>

<p1 id="resultText"></p1>

<script>
function checkZipcode(){
  var zipcodes = [12345,12344,12343];
  var validCode = false;
  for(i=0;i<zipcodes.length;i++){
    if (zipcodes[i] == document.getElementById('zipCode').value)
    {
    document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "YES, we deliver to your area!";
    return true;
    }
  }
    document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "<div id='fail'><em>Not yet, maybe next year!</em><br>We can <a href='http://google.com' target='blank';>notify you</a> when we deliver to your area.<br></div>";
    return false;

}
// Selecting form and adding an onsubmit event listener which
// is your original checkZipcode function.
var zipCodeForm = document.getElementById("zipCodeForm");

zipCodeForm.onsubmit = checkZipcode;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<h1 id="header">Are you in our delivery area?</h1>
<form action="action_page.php" method="GET">
 <input type="text" id="zipCode">
 <input type="button" onClick="checkZipcode()" value="GO"></input>
</form>

<p1 id="resultText"></p1>

<script>
function checkZipcode(){
var zipcodes = [12345,12344,12343];
var validCode = false;
for(i=0;i<zipcodes.length;i++){
if (zipcodes[i] == document.getElementById('zipCode').value)
{
     document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "YES, we   deliver to your area!";
    return true;
}
}
 document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "<div     id='fail'>    <em>Not yet, maybe next year!</em><br>We can <a href='http://google.com' target='blank';>notify you</a> when we deliver to your area.<br></div>";
return false;

 }
  document.onkeydown = function () {
  if (window.event.keyCode == '13') {
    checkZipcode();
 }
}
</script>
```